# Function that only acts on integers in a nested list?

Tags: python

```
speed=[['Adam', 50], ['Bob', 25], ['Charlie', 10]]

def update(lst1):
    nl=[]
    for i in lst1:
        nl.append(i*5)
    return nl
```

Is there a way to make my function only multiply the integers by 5 in the speed list and ignore the names?

Comment: Sure. Multiply the numbers and ignore the string? Presumably, the number will always be at `i[1]` and the string will always be at `i[0]`?

Comment: speed = [[name, num * 5] for (name, num) in speed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare update as such

```
def update(lst1):
    for v in lst1:
        v[1] *= 5
```

and then just call

```
update(speed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension

```
nl = [ [x[0], x[1] * 5] for x in lst ]
```